# Magento2 : How To Solve $(...).down(...) is undefined error in admin

Tags: magento2, customer, grid

[image]

Does anyone know how i can solve this error?

Comment: that was acl issue,if i set full acccess than Working Great

Answer (score 0):

That was acl issue,if i set full access to this perticuler store 
than Working Great